# How to disable port 443

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp

I have installed Apache 2.x.x. But right now I have uninstalled it from my pc. I try to install XAMPP, but the apache could not installed correctly.

Error:
Could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443

Comment: You have something running on the pot 443 - to see what issue the command `netstat -lanp` and look for what local address '0.0.0.0:443'. The last field tells what program is bound to the port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears another process is bound to tcp port 443. You can either change the configuration for that process to use a different port or change your Apache config to use something other than 443.

To find which process is using port 443, you can use **lsof -i :443**

To change the port that Apache uses, edit your **conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf** file. Change any instances of "443" to "8443" (or whichever available port you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

Did you start your service as root ? 443 port is before 1024, so it is reserved to root user.
Check if something run on 443 port, with **netstat -pntl | grep 443** (with root user)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your address from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1

Comment: His IP address isn't 0.0.0.0 - it's a virtual address